# Should I push on the stack, use a register, or a variable?

Tags: x86, stack, x86-64, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I need to preserve the value of a register ([ar]ax, namely). It gets modified after a function call, yet the value needs to be used later.
I Thought of three ways to do so (examples are on 64bit) :

1.Push it on the stack:

```
__asm__ ("pushq %rax\n\t"
         "call function\n\t"
         "popq %rax");
```

2.Save it in a register:

```
__asm__ ("movq %%rax, %%some_register\n\t"
         "call function\n\t"
         "movq %%some_register, %%rax"
         : : : "%some_register");
```

3.Save it in a variable:

```
unsigned long var;
__asm__ ("movq %%rax, %0" : "=m" (var) : : );
function();
__asm__ ("movq %0, %%rax" : : "m" (var) : );
```

Currently, I am using #1. It works as intended in my particular case, but I am worried, that pushing it on the stack might be a Bad Thing™. Most of my concern was: the compiler doesn't "know" about it being pushed. Since it appears to consume some space of the stack frame, which rather limited, that could lead to trouble in general.

Saving it in a register prevents the compiler from using it for its own needs. This might not be too much of a problem on x86-64, where there are many additional registers compared to x86. But if I need to use it on x86, that might be a performance hit, since the amount of registers is much more limited there.

Saving it to a variable might be a best choice. And since the compiler would probably save the variable on the stack && even assign a register, it might not be that slow. But it does make the code look rather odd, along with one additional variable that might make other people scratch their heads.

So the question is: which solution is the best one, i.e. what is Right Thing™ to do? Or maybe there is some more methods to preserve it, that I haven't thought of - ones that would be even better?

Notes: that function does not take variables and does not return anything, if that matters; The value in the register cannot simply be preserved via a some "higher-level" solution, hence inline asm; It has to be [er]ax specifically; I haven't tested the 3rd solution, so it might be a little inaccurate.

Comment: Why can't you create local variable in the programming language that you are inlining this code into. Then save the register in to that. The scoping of your language will keep the var around until you function returns.

Comment: One more possibility is to use r12-r15 which are callee saved registers. In general it is wise to check the resultant assembly in any case. The inline asm can inhibit compiler optimizations in very obscure ways.

Comment: @kingchris That would be solution #3 then. The problem is I need that value to sit specifically in [er]ax register when it's used. And there is no way without inline-asm I know of, to reliably make sure the register holds that value. I can't write to it with c++ (that is what I use).

Comment: @horsh I thought about that and wrote about it (in the section where I wrote my concerns on using a register. Yet I did not name r12-r15 explicitly). My concern was, as I wrote - on x86 (32bit) those registers don't exist, thus I would have to use one of the very few registers available. Along with preventing the compiler from using it.

Comment: Well if you explain why I must be in [er]ax maybe we can think of the possible side effects. Must it be in [er]ax before the function call or does something else use it after the function call.

Comment: @kingchris 'this' pointer is kept in that register (checked with a debugger). After that function call, it gets set to some other value. Right after returning from that call, it gets dereferenced (implicitly). That results in a segfault. Setting the value of 'this' is not allowed. Hence the workaround. P.S. This overwriting of 'this' only happens with compiler optimizations on, and works well with optimizations off. So it's either no optimizations or this dirty workaround.

Comment: Well. Isolate the smallest chunk of code including this workaround into its own C++ file. Then via your make file or IDE disable Optimizations for this small chunk of code. That the rest of your code will be optimized but this class won't be. Beware of so called optimization benefits. They often promise more than they deliver. Write a unit test thats call your code a million time with and without optimization. Track the execution times. Then decide. Good luck.

Comment: It should be noted that the compiler is unaware of the semantics applied to `%rax` in (1). There are no _guarantees_ it will hold the value you want in any case - outside the scope of an `asm` block. It isn't a robust solution, as it simply relies on a register allocation pattern that may change with compilers, or different versions thereof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solution 2, deeming a register won't be clobbered is audacious, especially with optimizations. The only drawback of solution 1 is that you won't be able to unwind the stack (if you need to debug the function call stack) as the only link between stackframes is the pushed [er]bp, and in this case it's no more consistent to [er]sp. I would definitely go for solution 3, which is clearer. Sure it adds a local variable for some obfuscated purposes, but at least it doesn't trick the ABI!

Answer (score 1):

None of your methods are correct, you can not safely keep something in a register outside of an asm statement. If you wish to pass a value between asm statements you must store it in a variable, GCC will keep it in the register if can, if not it will save it somewhere.